# How can I include the dynamic response properties of an OData web api operation on the top level of the response?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I built a c# web api based on .net 6 with integration of Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.
I use a Dictionary to include dynamic properties in my response:

```
    public class TestObj
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

        public TestObj()
        {
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
    }
```

Example response of my GET operation:

```
{
  "id": "TestId",
  "properties": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

But I want the keyvaluepairs of the Properties Dictionary on the top level of the response:

```
{
  "id": "TestId",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

Is that possible? I've tried different approaches but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your response doesn't look like OData's response. OData response should look like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44383/odata/$metadata#TestObj",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "TestId"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, please check your controllers and routes:

1. Your controller must inherit from ODataController
2. Your request is going to odata route

If you have a dictionary in your class and you use ODataConventionModelBuilder it will automatically make it OpenType: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

So, if you are using ODataModelBuilder you need configure your dictionary like:

```
 static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var odataBuilder = new ODataModelBuilder();

            var classExample = odataBuilder.EntityType<TestObj>();
            classExample.HasKey(s => s.Id);
            classExample.HasDynamicProperties(d => d.Properties);
            odataBuilder.EntitySet<TestObj>("TestObj");
            return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

Then your response will look like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44383/odata/$metadata#TestObj",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "TestId",
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to mention: 
In my asp.net 4.7 environment, all works perfectly. But after I migrated it to .net core (v6) I've got the problem, that in every response I get the enclosing properties {} attribute for the dynamic properties. I tried several sample projects with .net5 and .net6 (based on the WeatherForeCast sample of Microsoft), also with your sample code, but without success.

Comment: You mentioned: 
"..Your request is going to odata route.."
Usage of OData attributes like $select works fine, so I assume, the requests are going to odata route.

Comment: @Markus Can you show your configurations? What is your OData package version?

Answer (score 0):

I tried several OData package versions, e.g. Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.5.12 in an .net5 sample project.
Because my real goal is to migrate my existing asp.net v4 REST api to .net6,  I also did some tests with .net6 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.7 using VS2022

While slim down my sample code based on .net6 / Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.7 for this post, I had my first success!
Now the Swagger site shows two GET operations:
GET /DynProp
and
GET /odata/DynProp.
The /odata/DynProp operation shows the dynamic properties correctly!!!
Now I have a basis that I can use for my migration. Next steps will be: Configuring the routing (e.g. removing Non-OData operations from Swagger and customize the OData routing paths for my operations).
Thank you very much for your tips and suggestions that helped me not to give up.

My working sample code:

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;

namespace DynProp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DynPropController : ODataController
    {
        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetDyn")]
        public IEnumerable<DynProp> Get()
        {
            List<DynProp> list = new List<DynProp>();

            DynProp obj1 = new DynProp();
            obj1.Id = "TestId";
            obj1.Properties.Add("key1", "value1");
            obj1.Properties.Add("key2", "value2");
            list.Add(obj1);

            DynProp obj2 = new DynProp();
            obj2.Id = "TestId2";
            obj2.Properties.Add("key1", "value3");
            obj2.Properties.Add("key2", "value4");
            list.Add(obj2);

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

DynProp class / EDM:

```
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DynProp
{
    public class DynProp
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

        public DynProp()
        {
            Id = "";
            Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
    }

    public class TestDataModel
    {
        public IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var odataBuilder = new ODataModelBuilder();

            var classExample = odataBuilder.EntityType<DynProp>();
            classExample.HasKey(s => s.Id);
            classExample.HasDynamicProperties(d => d.Properties);
            var entitySet = odataBuilder.EntitySet<DynProp>("DynProp");
            return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs (in .net6 it includes all parts from Startup.cs)

```
using DynProp;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options =>
{
    options.Select().Filter().OrderBy();
    options.AddRouteComponents("odata", new TestDataModel().GetEdmModel());
});
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Result of GET /odata/DynProp:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://localhost:7171/odata/$metadata#DynProp",
  "value": [
    {
      "Id": "TestId",
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "Id": "TestId2",
      "key1": "value3",
      "key2": "value4"
    }
  ]
}
```